# How to pass(i mean display) the index value of <li></li>(under <ol></ol> default type) to <p></p> if <p></p> is inside of that said <li></li>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want to achieve here is to display the value of the index of < li >< /li > (under < ol >< /ol > default type) to the < p >< /p >(could be one of more, most likely just one) inside it.

MY INITIAL CODE:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <p>First p element in div.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Second p</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>A third p element in div.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>A fourth p element in div.</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script>
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    var y = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for(var j = 0; j < x.length; j++){
        for(var k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
            if(x[j].index == y[k].index){
                y[j].innerHTML = j+1;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

OUTPUT:

```
1.1
2.Second p
3.2
4.3
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
1.1
2.Second p
3.3
4.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using `querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementsByTagName` - more precise. Then don't get all `p` elements in the document; just get all `p` elements in each `li`. Probably a more elegant way to do this but the nested loop approach works:

```js
var li = document.querySelectorAll('ol li');

for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  var p = li[i].querySelectorAll('p');
  
  for(var j = 0; j < p.length; j++) {
      p[j].innerHTML = i + 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>
        <p>First p element in div.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Second p</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>A third p element in div.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>A fourth p element in div.</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Wow that was quick! Thank you very much sir for the advice appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. If this answers your question please kindly mark it as correct, thanks

Comment: I just did. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, both x[j].index and y[k].index are undefined.
What do you expect to happen when this occurs?

Comment: Sorry I'm not even sure if that line works because when I remove them including the if statement and the inner loop the output is still the same. Thanks for your response though. What I was trying to do there is to put something that would link the <li> to <p> but I'm not sure about that syntax it was just suggested by Notepad++ because I'm looking for something (attribute, properties, etc) that I can compare between <li> and <p>.